# IsotopeJS justified width cells in fitRows layout

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I'm a beginer of IsotopeJS and I'm trying to make a fitRows layout.

The problem here is I want rows to be justified so there is no blank space. But every cells should be the same width. So there need to be a minimum width for each cells and if we go under this width the grid change to get less cells in the row.

Is there a way i can achieve that ?

[image]

Comment: Desandro (isotope author) has a codepen showing how to do this here: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/zEAwi - Important note: you need to download another file to make this work here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/metafizzy/isotope-fit-columns/master/fit-columns.js

Comment: It's not what i want. [link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) as we can see they aren't align on the same row and the width of each cell is not dynamic (stay 100px).